# Calculate average from EditTexts

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, textview

In my activity, there are two buttons: one for adding an item to a ListView, which is formed by an EditText (where the user enters a decimal number) and another one, which will start the calculation. The goal is to calculate the average of the numbers entered in the EditTexts, depending on the number of items added to the ListView.

Here is the code of the Activity:

```
public class PersActivity extends Activity {

Button start, calcaverage1;
ListView MarkListView;
TextView markresult;
private SubjectAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subject_list_view);

    setupListViewAdapter();

    setupAddMarkButton();

    // Start button
            start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start1);
            start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {   public void onClick(View v) 
                {   
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PersActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);      
                        finish();
                }
            });

    // Calc average button
            calcaverage1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcaverage);
            calcaverage1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    addNumberFromText();                        
                }
            });
}

public void removeClick(View v) {
    Mark itemToRemove = (Mark)v.getTag();
    adapter.remove(itemToRemove);
}

private void setupListViewAdapter() {
    adapter = new SubjectAdapter(PersActivity.this, R.layout.subject_list_item, new ArrayList<Mark>());
    MarkListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.subject_list_item);
    MarkListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setupAddMarkButton() {
    findViewById(R.id.addsubject).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.insert(new Mark("", 0), 0);
        }
    });
}
void addNumberFromText()
{
    double total=0;
    for(int i=0;i<MarkListView.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        View wantedView = MarkListView.getChildAt(i);
        markresult = (TextView)wantedView.findViewById(R.id.subjectmark);
        double value=Double.parseDouble(markresult.toString());
        total+=value;
    }
    Log.d("PersActivity","total sum is "+total);
}

}
```

And here is the code of the adapter I used:

```
public class SubjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Mark> {

protected static final String LOG_TAG = SubjectAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private List<Mark> items;
private int layoutResourceId;
private Context context;

public SubjectAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Mark> items) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MarkHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    holder = new MarkHolder();
    holder.Mark = items.get(position);
    holder.removeButton = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.remove);
    holder.removeButton.setTag(holder.Mark);

    holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.subjectname);
    setNameTextChangeListener(holder);
    holder.value = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.subjectmark);
    setValueTextListeners(holder);

    row.setTag(holder);

    setupItem(holder);
    return row;
}

private void setupItem(MarkHolder holder) {
    holder.name.setText(holder.Mark.getName());
    holder.value.setText(String.valueOf(holder.Mark.getValue()));
}

public static class MarkHolder {
    Mark Mark;
    TextView name;
    TextView value;
    ImageButton removeButton;
}

private void setNameTextChangeListener(final MarkHolder holder) {
    holder.name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            holder.Mark.setName(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    });
}

private void setValueTextListeners(final MarkHolder holder) {
    holder.value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try{
                holder.Mark.setValue(Double.parseDouble(s.toString()));
            }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error reading double value: " + s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    });
}
}
```

The result will be displayed via TextView after pressing the button.

Here is a screenshot of the activity. Actually it has no errors, but the app stops when I try to start the activity.

[image]

**EDIT3:** LogCat error when pressing calculateaverage button

```
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "android.widget.EditText@536f3e10"
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:114)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at com.isa.gestordecurso.PersActivity.addNumberFromText(PersActivity.java:81)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at com.isa.gestordecurso.PersActivity$2.onClick(PersActivity.java:49)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-21 15:59:34.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1678):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hope there's a solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: If your activity stops when started, there must be stack trace. In Eclipse, check the LogCat view and post the stack trace here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code snippet, it looks like you forgot to initialize your `calcaverage1` button. That's why you are getting `NullPointerException` when you are trying to call setOnClickListener. Just declare and initialize `calcaverage1` button.

```
Button calcaverage1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
calcaverage1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         addNumberFromText();                        
    }
});
```

### EDIT:

For the second `NullPointerException`:
you have created a member variable `ListView MarkListView;`. But, you didn't initialize it. Instead, you created a local variable with the same name 
`ListView MarkListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.subject_list_item);` inside the setupListViewAdapter method. 
This is a totally different variable.

Replace this line as:

```
ListView MarkListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.subject_list_item);
```

with this line:

`MarkListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.subject_list_item);`

Comment: Why you can't? I mean, what's the problem? Just read the inputs and use the formula for calculating average. Can you explain what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Yes, sorry. My problem is that when I press the "calculateaverage" button, my app stops. I edit and add LogCat now

Comment: you have created a member variable `ListView MarkListView;`. But, you didn't initialize it. Instead, you created a variable with the same name `ListView MarkListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.subject_list_item);` inside the `setupListViewAdapter` method. This is a totally different variable. Edit this line as: `MarkListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.subject_list_item);`

Comment: You're right, but now I'm getting error again when pressing the button. I update LogCat error

Comment: Use this line `double value=Double.parseDouble(markresult.getText());` inside the `addNumberFromText()` method. You are passing incorrect parameter to the parseDouble() method

Comment: Sorry about that. Use in this way: `double value=Double.parseDouble(markresult.getText().toString());`

Comment: Now it works! But.. Id like to show the result in a TextView, not in the Log. Is there a way to doy it?

Comment: Of course! Add another textView in your GUI and initialize that in the activity (like you did for those two buttons). And then use the textView.setText() method to set your result whenever you are ready!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59746/discussion-between-hungry-coder-and-isaias).

Answer (score 0):

According to the logCat stack trace, you are getting a number format exception. Change the line:

```
double value=Double.parseDouble(markresult.toString());
```

To:

```
double value=Double.parseDouble(markresult.getText());
```